# cannot implicitly convert type void to int c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello So I am making a text editor and have two functions I call when clicking on different buttons in my GUI. So I call my "NewTextbutton" function in "CloseToolStripMenuItem" function. What I want is if the user clicks on cancel my program should not close.I though I can have a returned value from the function and then with if statment check if the user clicked on cancel or not. But I get error that I cannot convert Void to int. Can anyone please help. Thanks.

```
private int NewTextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox.TextLength==0)
    {
        TextBox.Clear();
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {

        if (this.Text.Contains("*"))
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes to the document?",
                 "Texteditor",
                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
                 MessageBoxIcon.Question);


            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SaveTextbutton.PerformClick();
                TextBox.Clear(); 
                this.Text = $"Texteditor                                                 dok1.txt";
                P = "";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox.Clear();
                return 0;
            }
        }

        TextBox.Clear();
        this.Text = $"Texteditor                                                 dok1.txt";
        P = "";
        return 0;
    }
}

private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = NewTextbutton.PerformClick(); //here is the error "cannot convert void to int"
    if (a == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("operation Canceled");
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: `NewTextbutton.PerformClick()` just clicks the button - so somewhere else, you need to have subscribed to the `Button.Click` event and respond appropriately in the button click handler.

Comment: This looks like it would benefit from a code refactoring. I would suggest moving the logic into a new function and calling it both at the button click event and at the menu item event. It would also ease if you later decide to unit test your logic

Comment: If you have event handler that perform actions needed elsewhere at some point, just use a stand-alone method and call that method when you need its results: from an event handler or any other method. You can ignore a return value if you don't need it, but you cannot make it return values when the method doesn't return any (an event handler is a `void` method).

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, an event handler usually returns `void` not `int`, so you cannot use `PerformClick` to get a return value.

You can refactor this way, for instance :

```
private int CheckWhatToDo() 
{
    // all the code that was in NewTextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
}

private void NewTextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CheckWhatToDo();
}

private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = CheckWhatToDo(); 

    if (a == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("operation Canceled");
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```